# org mode logbook note entry without logbook drawer?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to make a logbook-like note without it always being stuck in a `:LOGBOOK` drawer? For example:

```
- [2015-09-02 Wed 18:03] \\
    * 12.3 Export settings             :om:htmlexport:
      - Up: Exporting
      - [[http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html][Export settings]]
```

I like being able to just stick a timestamped observation anywhere with C-c C-z. Is there any way to turn off the automatic `:LOGBOOK` drawer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Where `org-add-note` sticks the note is controlled by `org-log-into-drawer`.  If it's `nil` your notes go into the body instead of the logbook drawer.  If you set `org-log-into-drawer` to `nil` you may also want to set `org-log-state-notes-insert-after-drawers` which will ensure that the notes go after `LOGBOOK`  and `PROPERTIES`.

I've been using this bit of advice to let me pick where notes go.  With a `C-u` prefix they go in the body, otherwise they go into `LOGBOOK`

```
(defun with-no-drawer (func &rest args)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((org-log-into-drawer (not (car args))))
    (funcall func)))

(advice-add 'org-add-note :around #'with-no-drawer)
```

Answer (score 5):

New here with no-reputation, otherwise I would simply have added a comment to erikstokes answer.

Using org-mode version 8.3.4 the advise above was not sufficient as `org-add-note()` had completed before `org-store-log-note()` callback function had been called.

So I took his example and made it two pronged:

```el
(defun sjm/org-add-note (func &rest args)
  "Set sjm/org-log-into-drawer to value of args (c-u), its value is read by sjm/org-store-log-note."
  (interactive "P")
  (setq sjm/org-log-into-drawer (car args))
  (funcall func))

(defun sjm/org-store-log-note (func)
  "calls org-store-log-note momentarily setting
org-log-into-drawer to nil if sjm/org-log-into-drawer is nil. As set by sjm/org-add-note."
  (if (not sjm/org-log-into-drawer)
      (funcall func)
    (let ((org-log-into-drawer nil))
      (funcall func))))

(advice-add 'org-add-note :around #'sjm/org-add-note)
(advice-add 'org-store-log-note :around #'sjm/org-store-log-note)
```

As it stands `sjm/org-log-into-drawer` is a global switch, but then so is the buffer `*Org Note*`; meaning you can only take one note at a time anyway!

---

`org-version` 9.4 (9.4.4) needs to have advice around `org-log-into-drawer()` rather than `org-store-log-note()`.  I now have the following instead of the above (corrected to reset).

```el
  (defun sjm/org-add-note (func &rest args)
    "Advisor function to go around `org-add-note'.  Takes optional
  count (c-u) and sets sjm/org-log-into-drawer to be used by
  `sjm/org-store-log-note'.

  The usage is thus:

  (advice-add 'org-log-into-drawer :around #'sjm/org-log-into-drawer)
  (advice-add 'org-add-note :around #'sjm/org-add-note)

  When you do not want to log note into a draw use C-u C-c C-z.
  Otherwise use C-c C-z as normal and it should log note as per
  standard `org-log-into-drawer'.
  "
    (interactive "P")
    (setq sjm/org-log-into-drawer (car args))
    (funcall func))

  (defun sjm/org-log-into-drawer (func)
    "Advisor function to go around `org-log-into-drawer'.
  Reads value of sjm/org-log-into-drawer, as set by
  `sjm/org-add-note', and if set returns nil meaning do not log
  into drawer.  Otherwise returns value from call to
  `org-log-into-draw'.  Before returning resets
  sjm/org-log-into-drawer for subsequent calls."
    (let ((ret
    (if (not sjm/org-log-into-drawer)
        (funcall func)
      nil)))
      (setq sjm/org-log-into-drawer nil)
      ret))
  (setq sjm/org-log-into-drawer nil)
  (advice-add 'org-log-into-drawer :around #'sjm/org-log-into-drawer)
  (advice-add 'org-add-note :around #'sjm/org-add-note)
```

Comment: After upgrade to Org 9 (9.3) this is no longer working.  I presume something changed. @narendraj9 answer below has it working again for me.

Comment: Could you post your revised solution that accepts C-u and works for Org 9 ? Many thanks !

Comment: @SOUser Added changes for org-version 9.4.

Comment: Both of these do not work for me. It will open the task file in the window and said: "Before first headline at position 1 in buffer inbox.org". Just to confirm the goal here: if this works, the note should always insert under the heading without going to LOGBOOK even org-log-into-drawer is not nil.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for:

```
(defun with-no-drawer (func &rest args)
    (interactive "P")
    (if (eq org-log-note-purpose 'note)
        (let ((org-log-state-notes-insert-after-drawers t))
          (flet ((org-log-into-drawer (&rest args) nil))
            (apply func args)))
      (apply func args)))
(advice-add 'org-log-beginning :around #'with-no-drawer)
```

`org-log-beginning` needs to be advised because `org-add-note` simply sets up post-command hook and advice operates only during that setup.

Comment: Agreed, this works for me on Org 9.3.  While my answer above stopped working.  Thanks.

Comment: Org 9.4 needed additional work, see my new workaround above.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change it by emacs' graphic interface:

```
m-x customize-variable org-log-into-drawer
```

then click in `Value Menu` menu and choose an option.

Note that if you change it this way, it automatically added an entry in your emacs config file such as:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-log-into-drawer t))
```