# Separating state change log entries from other notes

Tags: org-mode

Following Rainer König's example in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUvdddKZQzs&list=PLVtKhBrRV_ZkPnBtt_TD1Cs9PJlU0IIdE&index=9), I've customized `org-log-into-drawer` to be `LOGBOOK`. I've also added timestamps for various state changes such as from `DOING` to `DONE`, so that when these events happen, entries are added to the `:LOGBOOK:` drawer. I'm also using `org-add-note` to add notes unrelated to state changes.

The problem with this approach is that the notes are intermingled with the state change entries. For example:

`** DONE set up date-based plan files
   :LOGBOOK:
   - State "DONE"       from "DOING"      [2017-09-13 Wed 15:18]
   - Note taken on [2017-09-13 Wed 15:07] \\
     To add a timestamp, do ~C-c !~ (for inactive ones anyway) in insert mode.
   - State "DOING"      from "NEXT"       [2017-09-13 Wed 14:25]
   CLOCK: [2017-09-13 Wed 14:22]--[2017-09-13 Wed 15:00] =>  0:38
   - State "NEXT"       from "TODO"       [2017-09-12 Tue 15:45]
   :END:`

It's not easy to visually pick out the notes (which are often more relevant) from the state change events and clock events.

So my question is: can I separate the notes from the other information? I'd prefer for notes to go into their own `:NOTES:` drawer, but I'd also accept an answer that added notes to the body of the headline, outside of a drawer.

(Note: I'm aware of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/org-mode-logbook-note-entry-without-logbook-drawer), but as far as I can tell it controls the notes and other entries together, without distinction, so it won't suffice for my purposes.)

Comment: I am setting up emacs following Rainer König's videos as well, and I had the same doubt as you. I see your question has been posted quite some time ago. Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: No! Although I am tolerating it without pain and even forgot I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
(defun salih/toggle-logbook-on (&rest _)
  (setq org-log-into-drawer t))
(defun salih/toggle-stats-on (&rest _)
  (setq org-log-into-drawer "STATS"))

(advice-add 'org-clock-in :before #'salih/toggle-logbook-on)
(advice-add 'org-clock-in :after #'salih/toggle-stats-on)

(advice-add 'org-agenda-add-note :before #'salih/toggle-stats-on)
(advice-add 'org-agenda-add-note :after #'salih/toggle-logbook-on)
```

This will separate the "CLOCK"s into LOGBOOK and everything else into "STATS"