# Show notes in org-mode agenda

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode agenda, it is very easy to **add** notes to entries with `org-agenda-add-notes` (conveniently bound to `z` by default). However, these notes are filed into a drawer along state change notes where they are anything but accessible.

Now, what I'd like to have is a simple and *short* way to see all notes attached to a headline from the agenda view. This way, I could e.g. take down why an item is in a `WAITING` state (i.e., what it is I'm waiting for) without having to include much information into the headline itself and without cluttering the entry's body.

Since adding notes is so easy, it strikes me as odd that it should be complicated to view those notes. I looked for functions named anything with `org` and `note` but found nothing of use (exept of course `org-agenda-add-notes`). Is there a simple way to access those notes I don't see?

Comment: I think you can at least get the `WAITING` part to work.  Look at `org-agenda-log-mode-items`.  I think you need to add the `state` entry.  But I'm also curious how to get this to work for arbitrary notes.

Answer (score 9):

I like to store my notes at the bottom of my headings, e.g., after the end of the properties drawers.  To see the notes displayed in the `*Org Agenda*` buffer, I can type:

`M-x org-agenda-entry-text-show`

or

`M-x org-agenda-entry-text-mode` which is bound to the letter `E` by default.

The number of lines of text shown can be customized with the variable `org-agenda-entry-text-maxlines`.

Comment: Combine @lawlist answer above with collection of the note into the body using C-u C-c C-z as previously described in [org mode logbook note entry without logbook drawer](thttps://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28297/13835)